# How would I go about publishing Orchard.Core so I could deploy to a web host?

Tags: orchardcms

In Orchard 1.x, my setup was the following:

1. Cloned Orchard 1.x and kept it clean (unedited) and updated on my local repo.
2. Publish that clone of Orchard 1.x to another local repo that I would keep clean and update from the clone above as necessary.
3. Create multiple clones for different landlord/tenant sites of the Publish of Orchard 1.x, and set each up remotely in separate Bitbucket repositories. These would have staging/production branches.

The above is just a simplistic version of what I actually did.

With Orchard.Core, since it's currently in Beta 2 (or 3, I think), documentation is still being created. In some instances of documentation, I get the impression I can do a similar thing as the directions are to download the source and reference the appropriate NuGet packages. But I don't see much of anything specific about publish/deploy (except some information from blog posts from about a year ago - which is likely stale).

On the other hand, I see some blog posts mentioning that all you really need to do is reference the NuGet packages to run a site locally, but there is no further insight into the publish/deploy scenario. I can infer that maybe just publishing that might be sufficient, but I am not sure.

As it's still in beta, I have no intention of pushing Orchard.Core out on a live site. I just want to start preparing for when 2.0 arrives. I can test out locally whether or not what I did with Orchard 1.x will work with Orchard.Core, but I want to make sure I do it correctly. Just concerned I might be missing something.

Can anyone confirm the publish/deploy steps for Orchard.Core currently? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can publish the application.

Then, if you are on Windows and want to host it on IIS, you will need install the .NET Core Framework and the ANCM (ASP.NET Core hosting module).
In IIS, create a site pointing to the publish folder, with an application pool with 'No Managed Code' for '.NET CLR version' and 'Integrated' for 'Managed Pipeline Mode'.